# the breakpoint can not be inserted at this location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging

When I try to set a new breakpoint in my Asp.net project I have this message "Breakpoint can not be inserted at this location" in the bottom of the page
This message appears only in this projetc, I tried with other projetcs it works. I was able before to add breakpoints.
I tried to repair visual studio but it doesn't work, I think it's related directly with the projetcs since it work with others 
Thanks

Comment: At runtime or design time? Try cleaning your project from the build menu. Also try deleting your temporary asp.net folder and reopening visual studio. Using its or built in local Web server cassini?

Comment: it happens at runtime, I tried to clean the projetc, but I couldn't delete the temporary files even I am logged as admin! nothing change

Comment: The problem was that I set a breakpoint in private function otherwise it works on public

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a method at the bottom (line 1000) of the file had this issue.

Fixed by moving the method up to the begin (line 100) of the file.